# CiviCRM 5.9.1 on Joomla 3.9.2 Problems with the language

Tags: language

I've made civicrm (5.9.1) in a Joomla 3.9.2 installation. Only the English language is available, I find nowhere as I can change the language in German. Do you have a tip for me?
Greetings Michael

Answer (score 3):

Michael, Welcome to Stackexchange. The language will be available if you have downloaded and place l10n folder in civicrm.

To configure CiviCRM to use an existing translation:

1. Download the translations distribution -
   civicrm--l10n.tar.gz - from the CiviCRM Sourceforge
   downloads site. This tarball contains all files for the latest
   available translations.
2. Uncompress the tarball and you will see a directory called civicrm,
   containing two subdirectories called l10n and sql. The l10n
   directory contains a set of sub-directories named using their locale
   codes. (Example: the Canadian French translation files will located
   in /civicrm/l10n/fr_CA)
3. Copy this l10n directory, together with all
       its subdirectories into your CiviCRM codebase root directory. (note
       if creating the l10n folder manually it should be ell-ten-n, not
       capital-I-ten-n)

For Joomla this would be
   `site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm`. So if you
   wanted the en_GB language it would look like this

```
site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/l10n/en_GB/
```

For Drupal this would be `site_root/modules/civicrm`. So if you wanted the en_GB language it would look like this `site_root/modules/civicrm/l10n/en_GB/`

4. Login to CiviCRM (as a user with "administer CiviCRM permissions").
5. Go to Administer » Localization » Languages, Currency, Location
6. You should now be able to see and select all the localization
   options in the Default Language and drop-down menu. If you don't,
   and instead can just see the default 'English (United States)'
   option, check the preceding steps as the drop-down options are set
   by the directories under your l10n directory. Also be sure to
   confirm that the l10n directory is correctly named as l10n (that is:
   el-ten-en and not eye-ten-en).

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: it's so easy when you know where ...
I thank you for the quick help!
Greetings Michael

Comment: @michael can you please mark this post as answered if it solves your problem so that it will be helpful for others.